Django cycles/wrapped classes error with running server
I am learning to build and run Django framework web applications. Recently I am watching this video tutorial. I am doing everything as shown in the video, cmd shows that the server is working properly. But I can't open the web application in localhost itself:


I've tried to search for the error type, Google says it's a cycled import error and YouTube says there's something wrong with wrapping classes or something like that. I am a completely a beginner.
 from django.urls import path
 from . import views

 urlpatterns = [
     path('', views.home)`

Full code

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

I think you're not reached the right URL.
Could you please show your urls.py file?
You're reaching "/" and there is nothing at this address. Maybe remove the "/".

wow, thank you veryyyyyyyy much, your whole family and relatives. You answered so fast, i've put the link to pastebin for full source code. Bless you and your 10 generations

but no, there's nothing wrong with it

Hello, sorry for the late reply.
Is there not an issue with the path base/template/base/home.html ?
